Maximum update depth exceeded in search form using react-redux
I'm having a headache because of the infinite loop in react-redux which I have no idea what causes that, please help!!!
I'm trying to submit user status (Y/N )Here's how my form looks like
enter image description here
Here's the structure of my file
Users folder

SearchForms.js
Users.js
UserTables.js

Here's the runtime error I end up with:
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
SearchForm.js

import React, {Component, useRef} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {doToggleLoadClients, doUpdateSearchClientsOptions} from '../../apps/actions'

const getUsers = async (searchOption) => {

    const {page, userName, active} = searchOption;
    const searchParams = `?page=${page}&userName=${userName}&active=${active}`;

    return await axios.get(
        process.env.REACT_APP_WP_API + process.env.REACT_APP_GET_USERS + searchParams
    );
};

class SearchForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            userName: '',
            companyName: '',
            active: '',
            allUsers: [], //{"clients":[{}..{}],"total":123}
            userNameSuggestionsList: [],
            isDataReady: false
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleClearResults = this.handleClearResults.bind(this);
    }

    /// -- Common events ----

    // update the the table when first load
    async componentDidMount() {

        const searchOption = {page: 'all'}
        const responseData = await getUsers(searchOption);
        this.setState({allUsers: responseData.data.clients});

    }

    handleSubmit = async (event) => {

        event.preventDefault();
        const searchOptions = this.state;
        this.props.onUpdateSearchClientsOptions(searchOptions);
        this.props.onToggleLoadClientsFlag();
        console.log("Searching for search form:", searchOptions);
    };

    handleClearResults = () => {
        this.setState({
            companyName: "",
            userName: "",
            clientStatus: ""
        });
    };

    handleUserStatusChange = event => {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    };

   

    render() {
        const {
            userName,
            userNameSuggestionsList
        } = this.state;

        const userNameInputProps = {
            placeholder: 'Search User Name',
            value: userName,
            onChange: this.onUsernameChange
        };

        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Group as={Row}>
                    <Form.Label column sm="2" className="text-right label">
                        User Name
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Col sm="9">
                        <Autosuggest
                            suggestions={userNameSuggestionsList}
                            onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onUsernameSuggestionsFetchRequested}
                            onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onUsernameSuggestionsClearRequested}
                            getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionUserNameValue}
                            renderSuggestion={this.renderUserNameSuggestion}
                            inputProps={userNameInputProps}
                            theme={theme}
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Row}>
                    <Form.Label column sm="2" className="text-right label">
                        User Status
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Col sm="9">
                        <Form.Control
                            className="input"
                            as="select"
                            name="active"
                            value={this.state.active}
                            onChange={this.handleUserStatusChange}>
                            >
                            <option>ALL</option>
                            <option>Y</option>
                            <option>N</option>
                        </Form.Control>
                    </Col>
                </Form.Group>

                <Row>
                    <Col sm={2}/>
                    <Col sm={9}>
                        <Button type="submit" size="lg" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                            SEARCH
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        searchOptions: state.searchClientsOption.searchOptions,
        userName: state.session.userName
    }
);

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onToggleLoadClientsFlag: () => dispatch(doToggleLoadClients()),
    onUpdateSearchClientsOptions: searchOptions => dispatch(doUpdateSearchClientsOptions(searchOptions))
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchForm);

Users.js
import React, {Component, useState} from "react";
import {Navigate  } from "react-router-dom";
import UsersTable from "./UsersTable";
import SearchForm from "./SearchForm";

// Search users
class Users extends Component {

    render() {

        if (!this.props.id ) {
            return <Navigate to={"/admin/login"} />;
        }

        return (
            <div className="my-account">
                <Navbar {...this.props} handleLogin={this.props.handleLogin} />
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={12} className="mx-auto">
                            <h2 className="text-monospace font-weight-bold text-left mt-3">
                                Users
                            </h2>
                            <Card className="text-left">
                                <Card.Header className="card-header-account text-light">
                                    Search
                                </Card.Header>
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <SearchForm />
                                </Card.Body>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={12} className="mx-auto">
                            <Card className="my-5 text-left">
                                <Card.Header className="card-header-account text-light">
                                    Results
                                </Card.Header>
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <UsersTable handleLogin={this.props.handleLogin} />
                                </Card.Body>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Users;

UsersTable.js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {doSetOptions} from '../../apps/actions';
import {doToggleLoadClients} from '../../apps/actions';

/**
 * Calling api users
 * @param searchOption
 * @returns {Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>}
 */
const getUsers = async (searchOption) => {

    const {userName, active, page, orderBy, descAsc } = searchOption;
    const searchParams = `?page=${page}&orderBy=${orderBy}&descAsc=${descAsc}&userName=${userName}&active=${active}`;

    return await axios.get(
        process.env.REACT_APP_WP_API + process.env.REACT_APP_GET_USERS + searchParams
    );
};

/**
 *
 * @param self
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
 */
const submitUpdateUser = async (self) => {

    const {updateId, active, updateUseName } = self.state;
    let userName = updateUseName;
    let id = updateId;
    const response = await axios.post(
        process.env.REACT_APP_WP_API + process.env.REACT_APP_UPDATE_USER,
        {
            id,
            userName,
            active
        }
    );

    if (response.data.error) {
        this.setState({error: response.data.error.text});
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
};

class UsersTable extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            clients:[],
            errors: [],
            page: 0,
            total: 0,
            limit: 10,
            orderBy: "id",
            isDataReady: false,
            error: "",
            dsc_userName: false,
            dsc_active: false,
            dsc_id: true,
            showModal:false,

            updateId: '',
            updateUseName:'',

            errorSubmit: false,
        };

        this.handleSort = this.handleSort.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
        this.handlePrevious = this.handlePrevious.bind(this);
        this.updateTable = this.updateTable.bind(this);

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
        this.handleShowModal = this.handleShowModal.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    // update the table when submit search form
    async updateTable() {
        const descAsc = this.state["dsc_" + this.state.orderBy] ?"asc": "desc";
        const extraOptions = { page: this.state.page, orderBy: this.state.orderBy, descAsc: descAsc }
        const searchOptions = {...this.props.searchOptions, ...extraOptions};
        const response = await getUsers( searchOptions);

        this.setState({
            clients: response.data.clients, total: response.data.total, isDataReady: true
        });
    }

    // update the table when submit search form
    componentDidUpdate() {
        const { loadNewData } = this.props;

        if (loadNewData) {
            this.setState({
                page: 0
            }, () => this.updateTable());
        }
    }

    // update the the table when first load
    async componentDidMount() {

        this.setState({ isDataReady: false });
        const searchOptions = this.props.searchOptions;
        const response = await getUsers(searchOptions);

        this.setState({
            clients: response.data.clients,
            total: response.data.total,
            isDataReady: true
        });
    }

    handleShowModal(id, userName, active) {
        this.setState({
            updateId: id,
            updateUseName:userName,
            active:active,
            showModal: true,
            errorSubmit: false
        });
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value, errorSubmit: false });
    };

    handleSubmit = async event => {

        event.preventDefault();
        const self = this;
        //console.log('Update user info submitted:', this.state);

        await this.setState({ errors: []});
        let success = await submitUpdateUser(self);
        if( success ) {
            alert('User info already updated!');
            await this.updateTable();
        }

        this.handleCloseModal();
    };

    render() {

        const { clients, isDataReady } = this.state;
        const pageCount = Math.ceil(parseInt(this.state.total) / 100);

        let errMsg;
        errMsg = this.state.errorSubmit && (
            <Alert variant = 'danger' >
                <ul>
                    <li>Please select the Customer Status</li>
                </ul>
            </Alert>
        );

        const header = (
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User ID
                        &nbsp;
                        <SortButton
                            id="id"
                            handleSort={this.handleSort}
                            btnSort={this.state.dsc_id ? "fas fa-caret-down" : "fas fa-caret-up"}
                        />
                    </th>
                    <th>User Name
                        &nbsp;
                        <SortButton
                            id="id"
                            handleSort={this.handleSort}
                            btnSort={this.state.dsc_userName ? "fas fa-caret-down" : "fas fa-caret-up"}
                        />
                    </th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Status
                        &nbsp;
                        <SortButton
                            id="active"
                            handleSort={this.handleSort}
                            btnSort={this.state.dsc_active ? "fas fa-caret-down" : "fas fa-caret-up"}
                        />
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        );

        if (!isDataReady) {
            return (
                <Table striped bordered hover>
                    {header}
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colSpan="8">Loading ...</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            );
        }

        if (clients.length === 0) {
            return (
                <div className="OrdersTable">
                    No records found
                </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div className="OrdersTable">
                <Footer
                    page={this.state.page}
                    total={this.state.total}
                    offset={100}
                    handleClick={this.handleClick}
                    handleNext={this.handleNext}
                    handlePrevious={this.handlePrevious}
                    pageCount={pageCount}
                />

                <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.handleCloseModal} size="lg">
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Update Customer Info</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <Modal.Body>
                            <Form.Group as={Row}>
                                <Form.Label column sm="2" className="text-right label">
                                    Status
                                </Form.Label>
                                <Col sm="9">
                                    <Form.Control
                                        className="input"
                                        as="select"
                                        name="active"
                                        placeholder="Select One"
                                        value={this.state.active}
                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    >
                                        <option>Select One</option>
                                        <option>Y</option>
                                        <option>N</option>
                                    </Form.Control>
                                </Col>
                            </Form.Group>

                            {errMsg}

                        </Modal.Body>

                        <Modal.Footer>
                            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>
                                Cancel
                            </Button>
                            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                Update Changes
                            </Button>
                        </Modal.Footer>
                    </Form>
                </Modal>

                <Table striped bordered hover>
                    {header}

                    <tbody id={'usersTableBody'} >
                        {clients.map(item => (
                            <tr key={item.id}>
                                <td>{item.id}</td>
                                <td>{item.userName}</td>
                                <td>{item.companyName}</td>
                                <td>{item.email}</td>
                                <td>{item.phone}</td>
                                <td>{item.active}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={() =>
                                        this.handleShowModal(
                                            item.id, item.userName, item.active
                                        )} >Edit
                                    </Button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>

                <Footer
                    page={this.state.page}
                    total={this.state.total}
                    offset={100}
                    handleClick={this.handleClick}
                    handleNext={this.handleNext}
                    handlePrevious={this.handlePrevious}
                    pageCount={pageCount}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (
    {
        searchOptions: state.searchClientsOption.searchOptions,
        userName: state.session.userName,
        active: state.session.active,
        loadNewData: state.searchClientsOption.loadNewData,
    }
);

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        onToggleLoadClientsFlag: () => dispatch(doToggleLoadClients()),
        setOptions: options => dispatch(doSetOptions(options))
    }
);


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(UsersTable);



Did you know you are calling this.handleSubmit twice? Once in the form's onSubmit prop and another on the actual submit button's onClick prop. did you mean to call this.setState in the external submitUpdateUser callback? Is there a compelling reason why you are using React class components? They've been all but deprecated since early 2019... time to write React code from this decade. Same with the Redux connect HOC. Can you [edit] to post the complete error message and any accompanying stacktrace(s) so it's maybe a little clearer where to look?

After a couple of days, I found this line of code causes the infinite loop, somehow the loadNewData value keeps changing the value back and forth indefinitely.
const { loadNewData } = this.props;

    if (loadNewData) {
        this.setState({
            page: 0
        }, () => this.updateTable());
    }

I intended to update the table only when there's a change in option, so what I did was:
 if(prevProps.searchOptions != this.props.searchOptions) { ... }

Then the infinite loop goes away and the issue is fixed. But thanks to
Drew Reese for giving me a hint.
